# A decent way to structure Alamofire requests in swift app

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm a iOS noobie and have a method which loads some json from a server using Alamofire and the parses the JSON. My code looks a little like something below with the retry every 5 seconds.

```
func loadData() {
    let end_point = "likes/" + String(UserInfo.sharedData.userId)
    let url = MyConfig.sharedData.url + end_point
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON{ (request, response, json, error) in
        if (error == nil) {
            println(request, response, error)
            var products = ParseProduct(json)
            for product in products {
                self.likes.append(product)
            }
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        } else {
            println("failed will try again in 5 seconds")
            let delayInSeconds = 5.0
            let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.loadData()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This seems tedious repeating this retry for every Alamofire request I have. What is a good way to structure this code for multiple requests for multiple URLS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the retry logic into its own method. Pass the URL as a parameter, and then supply a `completionHandler` in which caller will supply its own custom logic:

```
func performAndRetryRequestWithURL(url: String, completionHandler:(AnyObject?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON{ (request, response, json, error) in
        if error == nil {
            completionHandler(json)
        } else {
            let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
            dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.performAndRetryRequestWithURL(url, completionHandler: completionHandler)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then `loadData` can use that function

```
func loadData() {
    let endPoint = "likes/" + String(UserInfo.sharedData.userId)
    let url = MyConfig.sharedData.url + endPoint
    performAndRetryRequestWithURL(url) { json in
        let products = ParseProduct(json)
        self.likes += products
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this something you usually use? Is it the standard to have just one method calling Alamofire (getting the .GET/.POST, Endpoint and Parameters) and calling a handler on completion?

Comment: @MarcosGriselli - The OP had some code that built and `endPoint` and `url`, and it seemed unnecessary to rebuild those every time it retried. Also, it struck me as a safe assumption that if he wanted retry logic for one endpoint, he'd probably wanted it for others. Just keeping it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: do you believe something like https://github.com/Moya/Moya is useful for a good Networking API structure?

Comment: Alamofire is pretty compelling, but Moya is less so, IMHO. It's certainly intriguing, but I'm not particularly inclined to integrate it into my workflow. To each his own.